# Upload image api imgur

Tags: laravel, imgur

I'm trying to use the imgur api to upload images for my personal blog covers, but I just get error after error, I guess I'm doing it wrong.
I'm using Laravel with Livewire 3, below I will show my code
I need help to upload it to my web server.

```
namespace App\Livewire\Articles;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use App\Models\Article;
use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ArticleForm extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public Article $article;
    public $img;

    protected function rules() 
    {
        return [
            // 'file' => 'nullable|mimes:jpg,bmp,png',
            // 'image' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
            'article.title' => 'required|min:3',
            'article.slug'  => [
               'alpha_dash', 
                Rule::unique('articles', 'slug')->ignore($this->article),
            ], 
            'article.body'  => 'required|min:7|max:65,535',
        ];
    }

    public function updated($property)
    {
        $this->validateOnly($property);
    }
    
    public function updatedArticleTitle($title)
    {
        $this->article->slug = Str::slug($title);
    }

    public function mount(Article $article)
    {
        $this->article = $article;
        
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->validate();
        $client = new Client;
        $response = $client->img(
            'POST',
            'https://api.imgur.com/3/image', [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Client-ID ' . config('services.imgur.client_id'),
            ],
            'form_params' => [
                'img' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($img->path())),
                'type' => 'base64',
            ],
        ]);

        $responseBody = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

        if ($responseBody['success']) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Image uploaded successfully',
                'url' => $responseBody['data']['link'],
            ]);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Failed to upload image',
            ], 400);
        }
                
        Auth::user()->articles()->save($this->article);

        session()->flash('msg', __('Article saved'));

        return to_route('article.index');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.articles.article-form');
    }
}
```

And in the view I have this

```
<form wire:submit="register" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="bg-black mb-3 p-5 flex w-full justify-center items-center border border-dashed h-52">
    <label for="img" class="cursor-pointer">
        Sube la imagen [ jpg, png, svg o gif ]
    </label>
    <input type="file" wire:model="img" id="img" class="hidden">
</div>
<div>
    <x-input-label for="title" :value="__('Title') " class=" text-xl text-amber-300 italic "/>
    <x-text-input id="title" wire:model="article.title" class="block mt-3 mb-4 w-full !bg-transparent border-0 text-xl italic border-b-2 rounded-none placeholder:text-white placeholder:text-xl focus:ring-0 focus:border-[#48ee06]  border-[#39c9d3]" type="text" placeholder="Escribe el título"  :value="old('article.title')" autocomplete="title" />
    <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('article.title')" class="mt-2 text-xl italic" />
</div>
<div class="  ">
    <x-input-label for="body" :value="__('Content') " class=" text-xl text-amber-300 italic mt-3 mb-3"/>
    <x-panel.textarea placeholder="Escribe el contenido" wire:model="article.body" id="body"></x-panel.area>
    <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('article.body')" class="mt-2 mb-4 text-xl italic" />
</div>
<x-primary-button class="!normal-case italic !text-[1.24rem] rounded-none w-full !p-4 shadow shadow-stone-950">
    {{ __('Article saved') }}
</x-primary-button>
</form>
```

Undefined variable $img

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried store the image first by this line

```php
$imagePath = $this->img->store('images', 'public');

//First Parameter ('images') defines a folder path where image are stored
//Second Parameter ('public') defines what storage you'll be using to save the image
```

Here's a complete documentation https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests

After $imagePath created you can put that inside the line to call stored file by path

```
base64_encode(file_get_contents($imagePath))
```

Hope that works

Comment: **I want to use the imgur api to save the image in imgur, not in local. @towewtem**

Comment: Yes but last time i checked, the only option you can upload file directly using laravel is AWS S3 (There's no imgur). So we're using this method to define your file path, store your file in local as temporary before uploading it to imgur and after you successfully upload the image, you can add a method to delete your temporary file. Reference: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/file-uploads

Answer (score 0):

Inside ArticleForm class, precisely on register function. You should use $this to get img public variable..

```php
$response = $client->img(
            'POST',
            'https://api.imgur.com/3/image', [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Client-ID ' . config('services.imgur.client_id'),
            ],
            'form_params' => [
                'img' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($this->img->path())),
                                                         // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This is for calling img public variable
                'type' => 'base64',
            ],
        ]);
```

Comment: **I already use it but I get this error in this line**  -->                                                                                                                                     $response = $cliente->img